# .htaccess: Redirect from a.com/example to b.com/example?param1=foo&param2=bar

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect from an old domain to a new one, and append some GET parameters to the redirect URL. If a subdirectory is specified with the old domain, this subdirectory should also be included in the redirection.

For example:

```
a.com
```

should redirect to:

```
b.com?param1=foo&param2=bar
```

And:

```
b.com/example
```

should redirect to:

```
b.com/example?param1=foo&param2=bar
```

I have found some examples for redirecting to another domain, but I was never able to append the extra GET parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single rule in .htaccess or Apache config of old domain.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?a\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://b.com%{REQUEST_URI}?param1=foo&param2=bar [L,R=301,NE,QSA]
```

`QSA` is used to preserve existing query parameters in old URL.